# Detecting user inactivity on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the most simple way to detect user inactivity and ask him if he's there?

Basically, after 3 minutes of the user not clicking on anything on the site, I'd like to ask him if he's there. He click's the OK button of a prompt of sorts and the entire page reloads.

Is there a jQuery script for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a jquery plugin "idleTime" that seems designed to do exactly what you need http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

[Demo](http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer)

Here is a simple implementation:

```
$.idleTimer(10000);

$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function(){
    var reload = confirm("Refresh the Page?");
    if (reload){
        location.reload(true);
    }
    else{
        window.location = "Log Out Url";
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The prompt never show up. I'm running this inside the Document ready jquery handler.

Comment: *Did you check out the demo page? There is a working example.* I'm not sure about all the details of your specific implementation: just take the working code, and implement it into your site.